# How to start a realtime process?

Tags: process, real-time

I looking for a way to start a real-time process or set a running process as a real-time process.

Comment: Which operating system are we talking about?

Comment: @AdminBee I thought all distribution is the same. LOL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start/set a process as real-time, you should use [`chrt`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chrt.1.html)

Usage to start a new process:

```
chrt [options] priority command [arguments...]
```

Usage to set a running process:

```
chrt [options] -p priority PID
```

Example:

```
sudo chrt -r 70 <your command>
```

or

```
<your command> &
sudo chrt -r -p 70 $!
```

Comment: I guess it was bad idea to put `-p 70`

Because it hanged my system dead. :D

Answer (score 4):

Of course, one can do this programmatically just by calling the relevant system calls.
There are various commands that wrap these so that one can do also this at the level of shell programming.

- On HP-UX, the command wrapper for this is `rtprio`.
- On FreeBSD, the command wrapper for this is [`rtprio`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?rtprio) with a nod in the manual to the HP-UX tool.
- On Illumos, and on Solaris and Ultrix before it, the command wrapper is [`priocntl`](https://www.illumos.org/man/1/priocntl).
- It is [`priocntl`](http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/priocntl.1.html) on Schillix, too.
- In [the util-linux toolset](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux) for Linux-based operating systems, the command wrapper is `chrt`.
- In the BusyBox toolset, the command wrapper is [`chrt`](https://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#chrt) with different options available than for the util-linux tool.
- In the ToyBox toolset, the command wrapper is [`chrt`](http://landley.net/toybox/help.html#chrt) with a third set of different options.